# WPF: CustomControl with sub property binding

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a custom control where the control properties has bindings to a sub property of the custom control's dependency property.

Both examples are based on the [BusyIndicator from Extended.WPF.Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/BusyIndicator/Implementation/BusyIndicator.cs), which should be bound to a [NotifyTask from Nito.Mvvm.Async](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm/blob/master/future/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs).

The first example introduces separate dependency properties for *Exception* and *IsFaulted*. These dependency properties are given separatly to the custom control on usage, using the properties of the respective NotifyTask:

**Example 1: Custom control with dedicated dependency properties (works):**

```
public class NotifyTaskBusyIndicator : BusyIndicator
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFaultedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsFaulted), typeof(bool),
            typeof(NotifyTaskBusyIndicator), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExceptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Exception), typeof(Exception),
            typeof(NotifyTaskBusyIndicator));

    static NotifyTaskBusyIndicator()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NotifyTaskBusyIndicator),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NotifyTaskBusyIndicator)));
    }

    public bool IsFaulted
    {
        get => (bool) GetValue(IsFaultedProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsFaultedProperty, value);
    }
    
    public Exception Exception
    {
        get => (Exception) GetValue(ExceptionProperty);
        set => SetValue(ExceptionProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Respective style:

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type customControl:NotifyTaskBusyIndicator}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type customControl:NotifyTaskBusyIndicator}">
                    <Grid>
                        <xctk:BusyIndicator
                            IsBusy="{TemplateBinding IsBusy}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            BusyContent="{TemplateBinding BusyContent}">
                        </xctk:BusyIndicator>
                        <TextBlock Text="Error on loading"
                                   Visibility="{Binding IsFaulted,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="Red">
                            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip
                                    Content="{Binding Exception, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
    <customControl:NotifyTaskBusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding ANotifyTask.IsNotCompleted}"
                                           IsFaulted="{Binding ANotifyTask.IsFaulted}"
                                           Exception="{Binding ANotifyTask.Exception}">
        <...>
    </customControl:NotifyTaskBusyIndicator>
```

Example 1 is working as expected. What I want is just give the NotifyTask as dependency property, which has all necessary information for IsBusy/handling errors:

**Example 2: Custom control with dependency property for NotifyTask (does not work):**

```
public class NotifyTaskBusyIndicatorEx : BusyIndicator
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NotifyTaskProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(NotifyTask), typeof(NotifyTask),
            typeof(NotifyTaskBusyIndicatorEx), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    static NotifyTaskBusyIndicatorEx()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NotifyTaskBusyIndicatorEx),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NotifyTaskBusyIndicatorEx)));
    }
    
    public NotifyTask NotifyTask
    {
        get => (NotifyTask) GetValue(NotifyTaskProperty);
        set => SetValue(NotifyTaskProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Respective style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type customControl:NotifyTaskBusyIndicatorEx}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type customControl:NotifyTaskBusyIndicatorEx}">
                    <Grid>
                        <xctk:BusyIndicator
                            IsBusy="{Binding NotifyTask.IsNotCompleted, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            BusyContent="{TemplateBinding BusyContent}">
                        </xctk:BusyIndicator>
                        <TextBlock Text="Error on loading"
                                   Visibility="{Binding NotifyTask.IsFaulted,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="Red">
                            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip
                                    Content="{Binding NotifyTask.Exception, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
   <customControl:NotifyTaskBusyIndicatorEx NotifyTask="{Binding ANotifyTask}">
        <...>
    </customControl:NotifyTaskBusyIndicatorEx>
```

Sorry for the long text. The binding seems not to work, the BusyIndicator is not show any error on example 2, nor the IsBusy-change is displayed. Maybe my binding type is wrong? NotifyTask is correctly throwing PropertyChange for each property.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: As a note, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has no effect in all your Bindings. It only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings, and has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Besides that, it seems odd that there is a BusyIndicator in the Template of a NotifyTaskBusyIndicatorEx, which is itself a BusyIndicator. That's two BusyIndicators. You probably want to have Style Setters like `<Setter Property="IsBusy" Value="{Binding NotifyTask.IsNotCompleted, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>`

Comment: Thanks for the responses!
I edited the start post and removed the triggers, they aren't needed, you're correct.

It is still not working if I just change the Relative Source to Self.
You consider derive from an other control? But I want to use TemplateBinding for Content and BusyContent, as they are provied by the BusyIndicator itself.

Comment: I am suggesting not to have a BusyIndicator in the Template of a BusyIndicator. Make a copy of the original Template and add the TextBox there.

Comment: You mean taking the template from here (github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/…) and modify it? That's a solution, but I thought that on of the advantages of WPF is that existing controls can be modified using a style without copying all its original stuff (like using custom controls).

Comment: I can only say it a *third* time. Having a control X in the Template for control type X results in having two X instances each time you use X. That is not what you want.